# why express js send index.html without any configuration

Tags: node.js, express

hello i'm beginner express. before ask question, i'm sorry about my english

i make a sample express code & file structure

-I-bin(folder) - www.js

I

I-public(folder) - index.html

I

I-index.js

and code is like that

www.js is

```
let debug = require('debug')('example-server')
let app = require('../')

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port)
})
```

index.js is

```
let express = require('express')
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let app = express()

app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
... below code just routing code...
```

but if i connect on localhost:3000 is render page in index.html

None of the above code sets the path to index.html.

Other example code uses the 'render' function, but not in this sample code. Why is my index example code showing index.html?

thank you~! :)

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` is the key. :)

Comment: ouch!. thankyou! :) . key is correct! and 
If express finds index.html in the currently set path, does it automatically draw the page?

Comment: for nodejs  , only specifiying the folder name means that he will look for any 'index'  file in this folder to execute it